After day light saving time switch - Apache FTP library "listFiles()" function returns null members even though files exist
In our team, we use the Apache FTPClient library to get files from a directory on some FTP server.
To be specific - we import into our project "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.*;
With the help of that library, we get a list of the files from the directory we want to read on the FTP server.
The function we use is the "listFiles()" function which according to Apache docs returns the follwing:
"Returns:
The list of file information contained in the current directory in the format determined by the autodetection mechanism."
In addition, it says - "This array may contain null members if any of the individual file listings failed to parse.."
According to that, we don't understand why before switching to day light saving time this function returns an array without null members and works perfectly fine, and after day light saving time switch - it returns an array with null members - even though there are files exist in the directory which should not be failing to be parsed.
We assume that the function fails to parse the files, because something goes wrong with the date and time of them and confuses it - after the day light saving time switch.
Moreover, we eventually solved the problem after removing the files from the directory and reuploaded them to it. After that, the function started working again and didn't return null members.
Thanks for the help!!

Please post [mcve] and log files.

I am dying to find out what this might have to do with day light saving. Honestly, I can't think of a single scenario. When you save a file the "created timestamp" is not decided by you, it's the system. Unless you've built your own os and it's total crap, I doubt that date or time can be invalid
